# Python convert list where one element has XYZ values to 3 integers

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a list of values where each element contains an x,y,z value.

Im trying to take a list of one element and find the distance between that element and a list of other elements. So List A has a main point and then there is a list B of other points I'm trying to find the distance to.

Example:

```
Listofpoints: [(6, 7, 2), (6, 1, 2), (7, 3, 7), (7, 1, 3), (6, 0, 3)] 
MainPoint= [(4,2,3)]
distance =  mainpoint and all points in Listofpoints
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should _first_ try to write code to solve your question and _later_ post the code you developed _to solve the specific issue_ — posting some random code you're working on doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: `[sum((x1-x0)**2 for x0, x1 in zip(fixed_point, point))**0.5 for point in points]`

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. What is the input, what is the output and how are you planning on getting there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have fully understood your goal, but if I do, I think you just overcomplicated your code. What do you mean with distance between "an element and a list"? Assuming you need a list of distances between the element of list A and each element of list B, here is some code.

```
def distance(point_a,point_b):
    d=0
    for e in range(0,3):
        d+=(point_a[e]-point_b[e])**2
    return d**(1/2)
def foo(list_A,list_B):
    l=[]
    el0=list_A[0]
    for el in list_B:
        l.append(distance(el0,el))
    return l
foo(list_A,list_B)
```

I didn't look in your code because I can't understand why you're using numpy for this simple task, why you're using random.sample and other stuff.

Comment: I did a terrible job explaining. The code I added was code for my whole program not just the problem I have. It seems the code you provided above solves my problem. Thanks!